# convert file to utf-8 based on the file command

Tags: ksh

Have an upload process, reads the file and using sqlldr it uploads the data to DB. I was getting invalid number issue while processing the file in sqlldr. Found the file is in UTF-16 format and then converted to UTF-8 format in notepad++, it started working fine.
Now i am trying to convert it systematically like below.

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 file_name >output_file_name
```

The file may be of different encodings, so i want to find what encoding the file is of, before  converting and then based on that do conversion. something like use file command to read the UTF-16 only from the below and then use it in the -f option.

```
bash-4.2$ file "/FILE_UPLOADS/Relationship (4).txt"
/FILE_UPLOADS/Relationship (4).txt: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have a subset of possible source encodings to consider? For example UTF8 ISO8859-1 UTF16-LE UTF16-BE

Comment: Why the [ksh] tag when your prompt indicates you're using `bash`?

Comment: UTF-16 and UTF-8 are transfer formats, not encodings. The encoding for both of them is Unicode. Are you talking about encodings or transfer formats? Note that detecting an encoding is impossible in general.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'd call UTF-* different encodings for the same character set (Unicode).

Comment: Do you specifically have to use `file` for the detection?

Comment: @Paŭlo, we have abstract characters (a **character set**), expressed as Unicode code-points (**character encoding**), which are represented in a byte stream using UTF-16 (**transfer format**).  Does that make it clear?

Comment: @TobySpeight i found file gives me the transfer formats, not aware any other commands. So using file command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `file` says *Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text* or with `--mime-encoding` *utf-16le*, it means that the file is encoded in UTF-16 with a BOM that indicates that it's in little endian.

`file` cannot detect UTF-16 text files (little or big endian) without BOM.

For UTF-16 text, it needs the first two bytes to be either 0xff, 0xfe (little endian) or 0xfe 0xff (big endian), and then checks that the rest of the first 64KiB of data look like text (only looking for UTF-16 encoded ASCII control characters that are not expected in text files).

For `iconv`, `utf-16le` means little-endian UTF-16 *without* BOM, while utf-16 means utf-16 with BOM, whether that's big or little endian.

So if you use the output of `file -b --mime-encoding` to use as the *from* charset in `iconv`, you'll end-up with a UTF-8 encoded BOM in the output.

Here, you'd probably want something like:

```
encoding=$(file -b --mime-encoding - < "$file") &&
  case $encoding in
    (utf-16[bl]e) iconv -f UTF-16 < "$file" -t UTF-8 > "$newfile";;
    (us-ascii | utf-8) ;; # already utf-8
    (*) printf >&2 '%s\n' "don't know what to do with a $encoding encoding"
  esac
```

If those are Microsoft files, as the CRLF suggests, you might want to use `dos2unix` instead of `iconv`. `dos2unix` (at least current versions) should be able to detect and UTF-16 and translate to the locale's charset (run it with `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 dos2unix` if you want the output to be UTF-8 regardless of the locale) and change the CRLFs to LFs and fix other quirks in Microsoft files.

Comment: This one worked. But the converted file have new blank line after every non blank line, and the encoding is utf-8

Comment: @Pat, `iconv` transcodes, it doesn't add characters. Maybe what you're seeing is the CRLFs from those files (that shouldn't show as blank lines though, what are you looking those files with?). Best may be to use `dos2unix`. See edit.

Comment: dos2unix is not installed in our servers, so used `tr -d '\r'` and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`vim` is able to automatically detect a few file encodings by itself and do conversion to UTF-8, so you could try and process your files in `ex` mode with:

```
vim --clean -E -s -c 'argdo set fileencoding=utf-8 nobomb | update' -c q -- *.txt
```

With `update` we also only rewrite files that have been modified in the process.

Comment: Thanks. I am using VIM "IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 30 2020 08:08:00)" and`--clean` is not an option. Execute this without clean but nothing happened, i had to kill the process after couple of mins.

Comment: @Pat, I don't have access to such an ancient version, but apart from `--clean`, I don't think the rest would require a recent version. It's likely `vim` is not happy about something and wants you do something about it, but `-s` hides that. Remove the `-s` to see.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `file -i`, it will return the MIME encoding of the file.

Something like:

```
iconv -f `file -i $file|grep -Po 'charset=\K.*'` -t UTF-8 $file > $file_converted
```

Another way is to use a more dedicated tool, for example:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/uchardet/uchardet
Then the command become even simpler

```
iconv -f `uchardet $file` -t UTF-8 $file > $file_converted
```

But you need to install it.

Comment: In my tests, `file` reports a UTF-16 file with BOM and little-encoding as `utf-16le`. If you pass as from charset to `iconv`, you'll end up with the BOM character encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: See file `file -b --mime-encoding` to get only the charset.

Comment: You may want to read [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you are right. Above code ended with "UTF-8-BOM"

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas my latest code: `CHAR_SET_IN=`file -b  "/FILE_UPLOADS/Relationship (4).txt" --mime-encoding`
iconv -f ${CHAR_SET_IN} -t UTF-8 "/FILE_UPLOADS/Relationship (4).txt" > "/tmp/converted.txt"` but still the converted file is utf-8 BOM. what i am missing?

Comment: `file` still returns utf16-le. You want `iconv -f UTF-16`